# MiKTeX and initexmf - Change user root priority without using settings GUI

Tags: packages, miktex, texmf

When running MiKTeX as non-admin, packages get automatically installed in AppData; sometimes, however, you want to manually install a version of a package in another root folder without removing the automatically-installed version. Unfortunately, the MiKTeX settings GUI does not allow moving user-added roots before the AppData folders and the `initexmf` documention provides no information other than saying you can edit config files using a command line option, but provides no information on where those config files can actually be found. How exactly would I go about changing the order of roots such that manually-added roots take precedence over the auto-included ones?

Comment: Imho the UserInstall (where miktex installs packages) is behind roots added by a user, only UserConfig and UserData is before.

Comment: UserInstall and UserConfig are the same folder for my distribution (`%APPDATA%\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9`), which is Root 0. UserData (`%APPDATA%\Local\MiKTeX\2.9`) is Root 1. The GUI doesn't let me move my added root before UserInstall/UserConfig or move UserInstall/UserConfig below the root I added.

Comment: I don't think that you can change it now, unless you try to change the registry keys. But it doesn't sound right, it should be possible to add roots before the root used for installation. You could make a bug report.

Comment: I actually did think of changing the registry keys but couldn't locate the relevant ones.

Comment: Btw: I do have a single user installation, so I don't know for sure if UserInstall does normally go behind user roots (but imho it is something user probably would want).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Switching to a single-user install resolved the issue for me, but I'll leave the question open in case someone can come up with a good solution for people who don't have the option of uninstalling a shared install and then reinstalling as user-local. (Then again, such a solution may end up requiring administrator access anyway so may not have a point.)